# javascript how to change variable on keyboard click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have been trying to make my first game in javascript, its a pong like game where two players move their rectangles around to bump the ball in the other direction. I want it so that when player one hits the "a" key, their character moves left, when they hit the d key they move right.

Right now, nothing happens when I click the desired keys.

This is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // things needed
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //positions of elements at start
  var ballposx = 400;
  var ballposy = 50;
  var balldx = 1;
  var balldy = 2;
  var balld2x = 0;
  var balld2y = 0;
  var p1posx = 80;
  var p1posy = 225;
  var p1dx = 0;
  var p1dy = 0;
  var p2posx = 620;
  var p2posy = 225;
  var p2dx = 0;
  var p2dy = 0;


  function draw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //goal1
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F3F0F";
    var goal1 = ctx.fillRect(0, 150, 50, 150);

    //goal2
    ctx.fillStyle = "#204050";
    var goal2 = ctx.fillRect(750, 150, 50, 150);
    ctx.beginPath();

    //ball
    var ball = ctx.arc(ballposx, ballposy, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    //p1
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    var p1 = ctx.fillRect(p1posx, p1posy, 40, 75);

    //p2
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    var p1 = ctx.fillRect(p2posx, p2posy, 40, 75);
    p1posx += p1dx;
    p2posx += p2dx;
    balldx += balld2x;
    balldy += balld2y;
    ballposx += balldx;
    ballposy += balldy;

    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
      var code = e.which;
      switch (code) {
        case 65:
          p1dx = 1;
        case 68:
          p1dx = -1;
        case 37:
          p2dx = -1;
        case 39:
          p2dx = 1;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    if (ballposy === 240) {
      balldy = -1;
    } else if (ballposy === 60) {
      balldy = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === 60) {
      balldx = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === 740) {
      balldx = -1;
    } else if (ballposx === p1posx && ballposy < p1posy) {
      balldx = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === p2posx && ballposy < p2posy) {
      balldx = -1;
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 10);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="300px" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> Sorry your browser doesnt support this!</canvas></center>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the keys

Comment: you need `break`s in all of your case statements

Comment: Nothing happens? No errors reported?

Comment: `game()` is not defined.

Comment: No errors reported... Added break's to all of my case statements and still nada

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a `keypress` handler every time you call `draw`. Do it once outside the function.

Comment: It would help answerers if you provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than the full code. While going through the process of narrowing down the source of the problem you may actually solve it yourself, but at the very least it will be much easier to get good answers to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding another `keypress` handler every 10 ms. So after a few seconds there are thousands of handlers running every time you press a key, and this is probably bogging down the browser. You should just bind the handler once, outside the `draw` function.

And in the function, you need `break` statements in each `case`.

Your `code` tests are also wrong. Lowercase `a` is `97`, not `65`. And the values of `p1dx` are backwards -- if you want to go left, it should be `-1`, not `1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // things needed
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //positions of elements at start
  var ballposx = 400;
  var ballposy = 50;
  var balldx = 1;
  var balldy = 2;
  var balld2x = 0;
  var balld2y = 0;
  var p1posx = 80;
  var p1posy = 225;
  var p1dx = 0;
  var p1dy = 0;
  var p2posx = 620;
  var p2posy = 225;
  var p2dx = 0;
  var p2dy = 0;

  $(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    switch (code) {
      case 97:
        p1dx = -1;
        break;
      case 100:
        p1dx = 1;
        break;
      case 37:
        p2dx = -1;
        break;
      case 39:
        p2dx = 1;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  function draw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //goal1
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F3F0F";
    var goal1 = ctx.fillRect(0, 150, 50, 150);

    //goal2
    ctx.fillStyle = "#204050";
    var goal2 = ctx.fillRect(750, 150, 50, 150);
    ctx.beginPath();

    //ball
    var ball = ctx.arc(ballposx, ballposy, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    //p1
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    var p1 = ctx.fillRect(p1posx, p1posy, 40, 75);

    //p2
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    var p1 = ctx.fillRect(p2posx, p2posy, 40, 75);
    p1posx += p1dx;
    p2posx += p2dx;
    balldx += balld2x;
    balldy += balld2y;
    ballposx += balldx;
    ballposy += balldy;


    if (ballposy === 240) {
      balldy = -1;
    } else if (ballposy === 60) {
      balldy = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === 60) {
      balldx = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === 740) {
      balldx = -1;
    } else if (ballposx === p1posx && ballposy < p1posy) {
      balldx = 1;
    } else if (ballposx === p2posx && ballposy < p2posy) {
      balldx = -1;
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 10);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="300px" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> Sorry your browser doesnt support this!</canvas></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the whole code, but ou should add the `break;` statement in every case, not just the default.

For example, your code should be something like:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  var code = e.which;
  switch (code)
  {
    case 65:
      p1dx = 1;
      break;
    case 68:
      p1dx = -1;
      break;
    case 37:
      p2dx = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      p2dx = 1;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding break and it still doesn't move, but it was errored out before so this does help!